# Obtain second tag inside a find_all

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags, findall

I am trying to obtain the second  tag inside a specific td but I'm not being able to obtain just the text of the second tag, as I am getting data from all the a. 
Later I will do a for to obtain the data of the 10 td. As you can see in the image I want the data of the second a inside each of the 10 td:

[image]

my code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga'
response = get(url, headers=headers)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)



match_containers = html_soup.find_all("td",{ "class" : "name table-participant"})

print(len(match_containers))

first_match = match_containers[0]

first_title = first_match.text
print (first_title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select for the second `a` tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga'
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print([item.text for item in soup.select('#tournamentTable tr[xeid] [href*=soccer]')])
```

Though you can drop the table id and use:

```
print([item.text for item in soup.select('tr[xeid] [href*=soccer]')])
```

For the rows of the table, with useful match data as a list, I would use:

```
rows = soup.select('#tournamentTable tr[xeid]')
```

Comment: Thank you, and How could I do to get at once the 10 matches?

Comment: matches = [item.text for item in soup.select('.ico-tv-tournament ~ a') ]

Comment: that what you wanted?

Comment: no, the ico-tv-tournament just brings data for the upcoming matches, not for all the matches in the table

Comment: with this code I just obtain one match, not all:  from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga'
response = get(url, headers=headers)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

match_containers = html_soup.find_all("td",{ "class" : "name table-participant"})

first_match = match_containers[0].select_one('a:last-child')     # the last a in the td (works currently)
first_title = first_match.text
print (first_title)

Comment: Seems some elements in table update once match time has passed. I have updated answer.

Comment: I'm getting an invalid syntaxis error in the last ]

Comment: print([item.text for item in soup.select('#tournamentTable tr[xeid] [href*=soccer]')])